# Portable GROUP BY clause rules?

Tags: sql

I don't use the `GROUP BY` clause often, but I think I have a general sense of its usage rules.
I also don't use a wide variety of databases.

I just got interested in the rules that make a GROUP BY clause "portable".

I made a list from some experimentation but I'm not too sure if it's comprehensive or correct.
I'm hoping someone with more experience can step in and check it.

---

#### Rules for portable GROUP BY clauses

A GROUP BY clause exists for these rules,

- If an aggregate expression is used and no explicit GROUP BY clause exists, a GROUP BY clause with an empty grouping set is implied
- Columns used in non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT/HAVING/ORDER BY clause **must** be in the GROUP BY clause
- Aliased expressions in the SELECT clause **must not** be used in the GROUP BY clause
- The GROUP BY clause **may** contain columns not in the SELECT clause
- The GROUP BY clause is **required** before HAVING

A GROUP BY clause may or may not exist for these rules,

- Any column **may** be used in an aggregate expression in the SELECT/HAVING/ORDER BY clause
- The ORDER BY clause **may** reference aliased aggregate expressions in the SELECT clause
- The HAVING clause **must not** reference aliases in the SELECT clause

---

Some elaborations follow,

#### Aggregate vs non-aggregate expression

Aggregate functions are functions like `SUM()`, `AVG()`, `MAX()`, etc.
They take values from multiple rows, and aggregate them to a single value.

An aggregate expression aggregates values from multiple rows.

A non-aggregate expression produces one value per row.

---

#### Aliased vs unaliased expression

An aliased expression has the following form, `expr AS alias`

An unaliased expression is just an expression without the `AS alias` part.

Aliased expressions are used in the SELECT clause

---

#### If an aggregate expression is used and no explicit GROUP BY clause exists, a GROUP BY clause with an empty grouping set is implied

The following queries are equivalent,

- `SELECT SUM(myColumn) FROM myTable;`
- `SELECT SUM(myColumn) FROM myTable GROUP BY ();`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uYQyR71a9N5QrdH3p3wVTT/0)

[PostgreSQL DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iJMkuyUpDHSeupMjLKxweN/0)

#### Columns used in non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT/HAVING/ORDER BY clause **must** be in the GROUP BY clause

Examples of valid queries,

- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn;`
- `SELECT myColumn + 1 FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn;`
- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn, otherColumn ORDER BY otherColumn ASC;`
- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn, otherColumn ORDER BY otherColumn + 1 ASC;`
- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn, otherColumn HAVING otherColumn >= 2;`
- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn, otherColumn HAVING otherColumn + 1 >= 2;`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wC3aczJ5aVEweuGevVK4ip/1)

Examples of invalid queries,

- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY otherColumn;`
- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn ORDER BY otherColumn ASC;`
- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn HAVING otherColumn >= 2;`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nsWYji5YJjhp4iCdx1jyKn/0)

---

#### Aliased expressions in the SELECT clause **must not** be used in the GROUP BY clause

Examples of invalid queries,

- `SELECT myColumn AS x FROM myTable GROUP BY x;`
- `SELECT myColumn+otherColumn AS x FROM myTable GROUP BY x;`
- `SELECT SUM(myColumn) AS x FROM myTable GROUP BY x;`
- `SELECT myColumn+otherColumn AS x FROM myTable GROUP BY x;`

[MS SQL Server - SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/92975f/7)

Examples of valid queries,

- `SELECT myColumn AS x FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn;`
- `SELECT myColumn+otherColumn AS x FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn+otherColumn;`

[MS SQL Server - SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/92975f/9)

---

#### The GROUP BY clause **may** contain columns not in the SELECT clause

Examples of valid queries,

- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn, otherColumn;`
- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn, otherColumn, myTableId;`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ju675VfE3pzm2Tb6CpffRz/0)

---

#### The GROUP BY clause is **required** before HAVING

Examples of valid queries,

- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn HAVING myColumn >= 2;`
- `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn HAVING SUM(otherColumn) > 3;`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aPjxCZUU7py1FDKmusydLX/0)

Examples of invalid queries,

- `SELECT 1 FROM myTable HAVING myColumn >= 2;`
- `SELECT 1 FROM myTable HAVING SUM(otherColumn) > 3;`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ZSVLrT7VVsbgFBkA6GwhW/0)

---

#### Any column **may** be used in an aggregate expression in the SELECT/HAVING/ORDER BY clause

Examples of valid queries,

- `SELECT SUM(myColumn+otherColumn) FROM myTable;`
- `SELECT SUM(myColumn+otherColumn) FROM myTable GROUP BY otherColumn;`
- `SELECT SUM(myColumn+otherColumn) FROM myTable ORDER BY SUM(myColumn+otherColumn) DESC;`
- `SELECT SUM(myColumn+otherColumn) FROM myTable GROUP BY otherColumn ORDER BY SUM(myColumn+otherColumn) DESC;`
- `SELECT SUM(myColumn+otherColumn) FROM myTable GROUP BY otherColumn HAVING SUM(myColumn+otherColumn) >= 3;`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/98sG3VPVoMu4LJHa94kdHQ/0)

---

#### The ORDER BY clause **may** reference aliased aggregate expressions in the SELECT clause

Examples of valid queries,

- `SELECT SUM(myColumn) AS x FROM myTable ORDER BY x DESC;`
- `SELECT SUM(myColumn) AS x FROM myTable GROUP BY otherColumn ORDER BY x DESC;`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iNSYoRy9NURyhnTifCRCNP/0)

---

#### The HAVING clause **must not** reference aliases in the SELECT clause

Examples of invalid queries,

- `SELECT myColumn AS x FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn HAVING x >= 2;`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v1mwGWG3DYUXoiF7HZLnT2/0)

---

I experimented with MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite on DB Fiddle.

I'm wondering if something is forbidden on a different database, but I think it's allowed because I've only played with those 3.

Or maybe something is allowed across (almost) all databases, but I think it's forbidden because of a brain fart.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: "Columns used in non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT/HAVING/ORDER BY clause must be in the GROUP BY clause" -- Not necessarily. If a column is "direcyly" dependent on the columns you are grouping by, you don't need to aggregate it.

Comment: "Any column may be used in an aggregate expression in the SELECT/HAVING/ORDER BY clause" -- Not really. Some databases impose limits on the columns. For example, large values such as BLOBs or CLOBs cannot be used. Also, some databases truncate the hashes to 255 chars at most.

Comment: "The ORDER BY clause may reference aliased aggregate expressions in the SELECT clause" -- Not all databases support this. For safety, use the original column names.

Comment: "If an aggregate expression is used and no explicit GROUP BY clause exists, a GROUP BY clause with an empty grouping set is implied" -- You need to clarify this. When no GROUP BY clause is specified, ALL columns must be aggregated.

Comment: "Not all databases support this. For safety, use the original column names."
--
Which databases don't support this?

Comment: "When no GROUP BY clause is specified, ALL columns must be aggregated." -- I'm pretty sure that's what the empty grouping set means.

Comment: "If a column is "directly" dependent on the columns you are grouping by, you don't need to aggregate it." -- That's fair. PostgreSQL and MySQL have different definitions of "directly" dependent, and I guess PostgreSQL is more "strict" about that.

Comment: I guess I wrote that statement because it's basically impossible to know if a statement with a GROUP BY statement is written correctly unless you know the structure of the tables involved. For example, `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY otherColumn` is invalid if `otherColumn` is not a candidate key. It is valid otherwise. But if one always puts the columns used by non-aggregate expressions in the GROUP BY clause, then one doesn't even need to know the table structure to know that it is valid. So, `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable GROUP BY otherColumn, myColumn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group by` is part of the SQL standard. While SQL databases often diverge from the standard, it's good to know the standard, rather than "SQL is what $database does". `group by` is pretty well standardized across databases, but there's going to be quirks.

Unfortunately the SQL standards are quite expensive, and have gone through several revisions. Fortunately, even an old copy of the standard is still useful. In particular part 2 which has the grammar and syntax rules. I'd suggest you find a copy and read through it.

In addition there are these free resources.

- [Jake Wheat's SQL Overview](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/) we can examine the [SQL:2016 group by grammar](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2016-foundation-grammar.html#_7_13_group_by_clause).
- [SQL-99 Complete, Really - Chapter 33 - Searching with Groups](https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest//chapters/33.html)

  - [Rules For Grouping Columns](https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest//chapters/33.html#rules-for-grouping-columns) is particularly useful.

---

Let's line up some of your derived rules with the standard. I'm using SQL:1999 because that's what I've got.

Yours.

> If an aggregate expression is used and no explicit GROUP BY clause exists, a GROUP BY clause with an empty grouping set is implied

SQL:1999.

> 6.16.2
>   The argument of COUNT(*) and the argument source of a `<general set function>` is a table or a group of a grouped table as specified in Subclause 7.10, `<having clause>`, and Subclause 7.11, `<query specification>`.

---

Yours.

> The GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING.

This is incorrect. The `group by clause` must come before the `having clause`, but neither is required.

SQL:1999.

> 7.4 <table expression>
>
> ```
> <table expression> ::=
>    <from clause>
>    [ <where clause> ]
>    [ <group by clause> ]
>    [ <having clause> ]
> ```

*SQL-99 Complete, Really* points out that [you can have a `having clause` without a `group by clause`](https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest//chapters/33.html#having-without-group-by).

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(a) FROM Somethings
> HAVING COUNT(a) > 5;
> ```
>
> This SQL statement means “if there are more than 3 a’s in the whole Table, display how many a’s there are”. As is usual, because there is a set function in the SELECT statement, there is an implied GROUP BY (). Therefore grouping rules apply: the select list in such an SQL statement may contain only single-valued Columns.

---

Yours.

> Columns used in non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT/HAVING/ORDER BY clause must be in the GROUP BY clause

SQL-99 Complete, Really.

> You must follow [“The Single-Value Rule”](https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest//chapters/33.html#the-single-value-rule) – every Column named in the select list must also be a grouping Column, unless it is an argument for one of the set functions.

---

Yours.

> Aliased expressions in the SELECT clause must not be used in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> The GROUP BY clause may contain columns not in the SELECT clause.

SQL-99 Complete, Really.

> Each Column in a GROUP BY clause must unambiguously name a Column that belongs to a Table named in the SELECT statement’s FROM clause. The name may be qualified, i.e.: it may be a . Such a Column is called a grouping Column: its values will be grouped for the final result.
>
> `SELECT a*5 AS b FROM T GROUP BY b;`
>     illegal: a is not a grouping Column and b isn't evaluated until the select list is; by then it's too late
>
> `SELECT a+5 FROM T GROUP BY a+5;`
>      illegal: expression in GROUP BY

Yours.

> The ORDER BY clause may reference aliased aggregate expressions in the SELECT clause.

SQL-99 Complete, Really.

> The superficial similarity of the GROUP BY clause and the ORDER BY clause often misleads people. The big difference is that grouping is done on the input (that is, the Tables named in the FROM clause), while ordering is done on the output (that is, the Columns named in the select list). So, although you can say “ORDER BY integer” (only in SQL-92 though) and “ORDER BY expression”, it makes no sense to say “GROUP BY integer” or “GROUP BY expression”. On the other hand, grouping Columns don’t have to be in the select list, as sorted Columns must.

Yours.

> The HAVING clause must not reference aliases in the SELECT clause

SQL-99 Complete, Really.

> Operands in the HAVING clause are subject to the same restrictions as in the select list:
>
> - Column expressions in both must be single-valued per group.
> - Column references must be unambiguous.
> - If a SELECT statement contains HAVING without a preceding GROUP BY clause, the select list can’t include any references to Columns belonging to a Table named in the FROM clause unless those references are used with a set function.
> - If HAVING includes a subquery, it can’t include outer Column references unless those references are to grouping Columns or are used with a set function.

And so on.

Comment: Your “Single-Value Rule” may be incomplete as of today. There's a third case, when a column is "directly dependent" on the grouped columns, For example if you are grouping by the PK, then you can type any other column(s) of the table in non-aggregated form.

Comment: @TheImpaler Is there a situation where grouping by the primary key is useful? That is, is there a situation when `select ... group by id` and `select ...` are different?

Comment: "The group by clause must come before the having clause, but neither is required." -- I always thought so, too. That it is okay to use the having clause without a group by clause; but [SQLite threw me for a loop](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ZSVLrT7VVsbgFBkA6GwhW/0). And I'm interested in queries that are portable across a bunch of databases, including SQLite.

Comment: "`SELECT a+5 FROM T GROUP BY a+5;` illegal: expression in GROUP BY" -- This interests me. I tested PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite and MSSQL and they all allow this. I wonder if the standard has chaged since then, or if they all decided to add this extension. I don't think I've ever used an expression in GROUP BY, but I assumed it was allowed. Maybe I should try and get my hands on a copy...

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it's pretty detailed, answers most of my question (which I'll admit was really many questions), and points me to more reading material

Comment: [Contrived example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZghGo4bEzQkYfeshh1QtL/0) where one may want to GROUP BY a table's primary key

Comment: I just got a copy of the 2016 standard, part 2. It really doesn't say that arbitrary expressions can be part of the GROUP BY clause. So, I guess arbitrary expressions in the GROUP BY clause is just an extension enabled by the 4 databases I checked ._.

Comment: @JustinAnyhowStep Yes, using expressions and column aliases in `group by` is a very obvious extension. Check out the Compatibility section of [the Postgres `SELECT` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html). In general, Postgres documents their deviations from the standard. On final resource, [Hyperpolyglot](http://hyperpolyglot.org/scripting). I'd encourage you to document your findings of SQL extensions and deviations similarly.